# Api gateway "malformed lambda proxy response" when returning a string from java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

```
public class LambdaFunction implements RequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, String> {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Map<String, Object> event, Context context) {
        return gson.toJson(new Response());
    }
    
    class Response {
        int statusCode;
        Map<String, String> headers;
        Map<String, String> body;
        
        public Response(){
        this.statusCode = 300;
        this.headers = new HashMap<>();
        this.body = new HashMap<>();
        this.body.put("key1", "value1");
        }
    } 
}
```

I set up an endpoint with proxy integration for the api gateway, this is the final part of the log:

```
Mon Sep 28 09:30:27 UTC 2020 : Received response. Status: 200, Integration latency: 16 ms
Mon Sep 28 09:30:27 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response headers: {Date=Mon, 28 Sep 2020 09:30:27 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=68, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=string, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amz-Executed-Version=$LATEST, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=string;sampled=0}
Mon Sep 28 09:30:27 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response body before transformations: "{\"statusCode\":300,\"headers\":{},\"body\":{\"key1\":\"value1\"}}"
Mon Sep 28 09:30:27 UTC 2020 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
Mon Sep 28 09:30:27 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 502
```

I have no idea what to do, I have already looked up a lot of questions but none of them used java. I also tried to return a Response directly and even that doesn't work properly. The gateway doesn't return an error but returns a 200 with empty body (which should be a 300 with a body)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to use the [the Java Lambda events code](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/master/aws-lambda-java-events/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/events/APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent.java) then you need to make sure that the fields are correct in the response.  As you can see, the `body` is just a String:

```
private Integer statusCode;
private Map<String, String> headers;
private String body;
private Boolean isBase64Encoded;
```

Answer (score 0):

Going through the official code samples I found [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/master/sample-apps/java-events/src/main/java/example/HandlerApiGateway.java) the class `APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent`, I made my own `Response` class work by making it implement `Serializable` and making public getters. I wasn't able to make it work with a json string though.